# single quote in cbind for appending data to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to understand the syntax in the following line of code. What does the single quote inside the cbind function do here? Please explain with an example, if possible. For complete code sample, please visit this [site](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commit/eda2335c0f6ec326c7ff3fa72706275de8cebd19).

```
Type:

'after' : logical
'check' : vector

if (after) cbind(data, ' ' = check) else cbind(' ' = check, data)
```

Comment: Add "empty" named column - `' '` with `check` object values before or after data columns.

Comment: I was surprised the column name didn't become ".". I thought cbind.data.frame would have called 'check.names'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a handy way to give the appended column an empty (looking) name in the resulting data.frame.

Compare:

```
> data <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
> cbind(data, 1:3)
  a b 1:3
1 1 4   1
2 2 5   2
3 3 6   3
> cbind(data, ' '=1:3)
  a b  
1 1 4 1
2 2 5 2
3 3 6 3

## And just to see for yourself that the column name is not really empty...
> names(cbind(data, ' '=1:3))
[1] "a" "b" " "
```